# Почему выводит "Tom" а не "Mike", ведь здесь изменяется значение по ссылке?

Tags: c#, list

```
var people = new List<string>() { "Tom", "Bob", "Sam" };
string firstPerson = people[0]; // получаем первый элемент
Console.WriteLine(firstPerson); // Tom
people[0] = "Mike";     // изменяем первый элемент     
Console.WriteLine(firstPerson); // Tom
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var people = new List<string>() { "Tom", "Bob", "Sam" };  // поместили в массив три указателя
string firstPerson = people[0]; // получили значение первого указателя
Console.WriteLine(firstPerson); // вывели данные, на которые он указывает
people[0] = "Mike";             // в первый элемент поместили другой указатель
Console.WriteLine(firstPerson); // вывели данные, на какие указывает сохраненный указатель
```

Comment: Лучше здесь использовать термин "ссылка" (reference), а не "указатель" (pointer). Потому что это 2 немного разные штуковины.

Comment: @aepot ссылка - это синтаксически подслаженный указатель. Или вы имеете в виду еще счетчик ссылок?

Comment: Я имею в виду что указатель - это неуправляемый контекст, прямая работа с памятью, а ссылка - управляемый контекст, работа со управляемыми ссылочными типами. Тип на указателе может быть любой, хоть `void`, для ссылки же используется строгая типизация.